# Inserting batches in Azure table storage using the Azure.Data.Tables SDK does not appear to be doable

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure.data.tables

I am upgrading all my azure table storage functionality to Azure.Data.Tables library since the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table SDK is being deprecated.

I loaded batches of data easily using this code from the Cosmos package.

```
try {
        var pks = entities.Select(x => x.PartitionKey).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var pk in pks) {
            await AddSymbolIfNotExistOrUpdateLastRecordDateAsync(pk, entities[0].RowKey);
            var records = entities.Where(x => x.PartitionKey == pk).Distinct().ToList();  // partition key is the symbol
            var batches = records.Batch(100);  //batching max value is 100
            completionMessage.Append($" A storage batch started for {records.Count} {pk} records into the table: {tableName} ");

            #region BATCH JOB

            //Iterating through each batch
            foreach (var block in batches) {
                var batchOperationObj = new TableBatchOperation();
                foreach (var record in block) {
                    batchOperationObj.InsertOrReplace(record);
                }
                try {
                    var worked = await table?.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperationObj)! != null;
                    if (worked) {
                        batchResponse.NumberOfRecordsProcessed += batchOperationObj.Count;
                        batchOperationObj.Clear();
                    }
                } // rest removed for brevity
```

I cannot find any methods, samples or tutorials that show how to insert batches using this SDK. Is it possible it is not doable using it? There are only Add methods for singular entities.

Any thoughts appreciated, as I load thousands of records at a time and just can't imagine doing via iteration is the only way to go.

Comment: @Guarav Mantri...you're the expert here, please reply. Thank you!

Comment: See client library for net : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction#azure-storage-data-api-and-library-references

Comment: Thanks, but there is limited information on batching using Tables library. Already spent a bunch of time there.

Comment: And by limited, I mean it doesnt appear that there is a way to do it, only single entity Add methods

Comment: Do you know about BulkCopy?  You have to create a table with entries, but then can copy to database : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal

Comment: So,the answer is, I am correct? There is no bulk/batch inserting available in this SDK, which seems to me to be an awfully important feature for an SDK to be missing from the one it replaced. Creating a table and copy pasting it seems kludgish to me, Ill review those docs, but I am also not using Azure Data Factory which at first glance is what those docs are referring to.  I'll iterate for now

Comment: I thought you are replacing the SDK.  Why can't you use a Data Factory?  Where are you getting the data?  How are you reading the data?  Putting data in to a datatable is very simply.

Comment: I load entities into azure table storage after reading the data from a csv file and creating List<ITableEntity> from the file. These are all new table data additions, not updates or upserts. This runs for multiple files and different tables. It was so easy with the Microsoft.Azure.cosmos.Table SDK, why they dont have batch uploading in the Azure.Data.Tables SDK is beyond me.

Comment: You can can connect to CSV using OLEDB.  Then connect to the Azure.  Bulkcopy will copy the data between the two connections.  Code will look like this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/ole-db-how-to/bulk-copy-data-using-irowsetfastload-ole-db?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do so. You will just need to use [`TableTransactionAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tabletransactionaction?view=azure-dotnet) to add an entity to the batch and then call [`TableClient.SubmitTransactionAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.submittransactionasync?view=azure-dotnet) to save entities in the batch.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
TableClient client = new TableClient(new Uri(""));
var transactionActions = new List<TableTransactionAction>()
{
    new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, new TableEntity("pk", "rk1")),
    new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, new TableEntity("pk", "rk2")),
    new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, new TableEntity("pk", "rk3")),
    new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, new TableEntity("pk", "rk4")),
    new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, new TableEntity("pk", "rk5")),
};
await client.SubmitTransactionAsync(transactionActions);
```

Comment: @Guarav Mantri... Is batching still required (100 count maximum) or is there another size restriction per batch of submissions. Can multiple different partition keys be submitted at one time?

Comment: No for both. Max 100 entities per batch and all entities in the batch should have same partition key. Furthermore, size of the batch cannot be more than 4MB (not sure about the exact size though).

Comment: How can we see if the size limit has been exceeded without submitting the transaction?
I don't understand how to implement batch splitting based on size.